# Call async function into catch from interceptor Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to call an async method to wait after call other function. I'm not very expert in terms of rxjs and also I've never worked with async/await calls.

I have this logic into the interceptor

```
public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    if (req.headers.get('a-header')) {
      const headers = req.headers.delete('a-header');

      return next.handle(req.clone({ headers, withCredentials: true }));
    }

    return next.handle(req.clone({ withCredentials: true })).catch((err: Error) => {
      if (!(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) || (err as HttpErrorResponse).status !== 401) {
        return throwError(err);
      }
      this.error.notify401Error(err);
      //NEED TO AWAIT THE NEXT RESPONSE
      this.callXApi(next);
      //AND THEN CONTINUE WITH THIS CALL
      this.redirectSignedOut();
      return empty();
    });
  }
```

Note that I need to call `CallXApi`, wait until finished, and then continue with `redirectSignedOut` function.

```
  private callXApi(): void {
    const { uri } = this.config;

    this.httpClient
      .delete(uri, { withCredentials: true })
      .subscribe(() => { console.log('completed.') }, (err) => throwError(err));
  }
```

How can I achieve that?

**UPDATE**

I achieved this by changing the next code

```
return <any>next.handle(req.clone({ withCredentials: true })).catch(async (err: Error) => {
  if (!(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) || (err as HttpErrorResponse).status !== 401) {
    return throwError(err);
  }
  this.errorEventService.notify401Error(err);
  await this.callXApi();

  return EMPTY;
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Comment: can you modify `callXApi()`?

Comment: yes, I can modify whatever I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
 return next.handle(req.clone({ withCredentials: true })).catch(async (err: Error) => {
  if (!(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) || (err as HttpErrorResponse).status !== 401) {
    return throwError(err);
  }
  this.error.notify401Error(err);
  //NEED TO AWAIT THE NEXT RESPONSE
  await this.callXApi(next);
  //AND THEN CONTINUE WITH THIS CALL
  this.redirectSignedOut();
  return empty();
});
```